# Jenkins behind an ALB redirects https to http on login and save

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, jenkins, aws-application-load-balancer

## Problem

On submit/save actions, Jenkins improperly redirects to `http` on port `443` causing the error message to be returned `The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port`

## High Level Architecture

[image]

- In AWS, an ACM is attached to the ALB
- A listener rule in the ALB is configured to redirect `http` to `https`
- *By default redirect `8080` to `443`*
  [image]
- The **Jenkins Server** is behind `nginx` and listens to port `8080`

## Steps to Reproduce the Issue

1. In your browser, go to `http://myjenkinsexample.com:8080`
2. `http://myjenkinsexample.com:8080` is redirected to `https://myjenkinsexample.com`
3. Click **Login** and submit login credentials
4. ERROR

- Browser redirected to `http://myjenkinsexample.com:443`
- An error page is displayed with the following error

> 400 Bad Request,
> The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

[image]

## Question

Where do I fix the configuration so that on "submit" requests, it redirects to `https` on `443`?

Answer (score 0):

I settled the problems :

1. nginx configuration edit.

```
upstream jenkins {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}


server {
  server_name jenkins-testpp.com;
  listen 80;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=360s;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_next_upstream error;
    proxy_pass http://jenkins;
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    proxy_read_timeout 150;
  }
}
```

2. jenkins configuration edit.

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/jenkins

JENKINS_ARGS="--httpPort=8080 --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1"
```

3. sudo systemctl restart jenkins
4. sudo systemctl restart nginx
5. connect jenkins url.